# Ansible loop using multi-ter group_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to dynamically create templates in ansible using group_vars but cannot seem to get the nested loop working.

In group_vars, I have

```
my_environment:
  serv1:
    foo: 2
    bar: 3
    baz: 3
  serv2:
    foo: 1
```

I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
/serv1/foo1
/serv1/foo2

/serv1/bar1
/serv1/bar2
/serv1/bar3

/serv1/baz1
/serv1/baz2
/serv1/baz3

/serv2/foo1
```

Once the above is created, I want to put a template file into each directory so the final result would be:

```
/serv1/bar1/template
```

and

```
/serv2/foo1/template
```

etc.

My playbook:

```
- debug: msg="{{ ce }}"
  with_list:
    - "{{ item.value }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: ce
```

The above outputs:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "ce": {
        "bar": 3,
        "baz": 3,
        "foo": 2
    },
    "msg": {
        "bar": 3,
        "baz": 3,
        "foo": 2
    }
}
```

The question is, how do I use the value of `foo` to iterate `2` times to create the structure? Whenever I use an `include: with_dict` or `include: with_list` I keep on just getting the above list? I can't find a way to traverse down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write your own lookup plugin that will form the desired list of paths from your input.

Using standard lookups(loops) you can do it this way:
x.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_environment:
      serv1:
        foo: 2
        bar: 3
        baz: 3
      serv2:
        foo: 1
  tasks:
    - include: x2.yml
      with_dict: "{{ my_environment }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: my_server
```

x2.yml:

```
- include: x3.yml
  with_dict: "{{ my_server.value }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: my_param
```

x3.yml:

```
- debug: var=item
  with_sequence: end={{ my_param.value }} format=/{{ my_server.key }}/{{ my_param.key }}%1d/template
```

`debug` in x3.yml you can replace with `template` and use `{{ item }}` as `dest`.

Comment: This is painful (not being able to do nested iterative loops inside a single play in ansible), but your solution is a good workaround; thank you!!

Comment: This answer is incredibly helpful!   Includes are the inner loop I was looking for.  Thanks. (Baffled by why this would have been downvoted.  This is better than any other answer I've found)