# Iterating through nested dictionaries in Ansibles group_vars

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to iteratively loop through a group_var that we have inside of our ansible environment and pull the salary value and use it inside of the command module.  I have the following file inside of my ansible/groups_vars file -

```
people:
  george:
    lastname: smith
    job:
      title: associate
      salary: 60    

  chris:
    lastname: george
    job:
      title: senior
      salary: 70

  greg:
    lastname: anderson
    job:
      title: director
      salary: 95
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
- name: Run module check command against every docroot
  command: 'drush  --root=/var/www/html/wwwroot/{{item.0.salary}}/docroot en update'
  with_subelements:
   - "{{ people }}"
   -  job.salary
```

The error that I am seeing is:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "the key salary should point to a list, got '60'"}

I put together this solution by looking at the following questions on here:

[Ansible with_subelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908715/ansible-with-subelements)
[Ansible loop using multi-ter group_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770706/ansible-loop-using-multi-ter-group-vars)
[Ansible with subelements referencing a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311622/ansible-with-subelements-referencing-a-dict)

Trying to set the value to .0 or .1 seems to make it look for a dictionary, and setting it to [0] or [1] says:

> {"msg": "could not find 'salary[1]' key in iterated item '{u'title': associate, u'salary': u'60'}"}

I feel like I'm really close to getting this working, but there's just a small piece that I am missing.  How can I get it to iteratively loop through and pull that specific piece of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no nested dictionaries nor lists to loop over in the example you posted. You want to iterate over a single dictionary and refer to its values.

Here is an answer to your question:

```
- name: Run module check command against every docroot
  command: 'drush  --root=/var/www/html/wwwroot/{{item.value.job.salary}}/docroot en update'
  with_dict:
    - "{{ people }}"
```